# Centering one image and aligning one to the left in an inline-block

Tags: html, css

How would I center topbanner.png at the top and align logo.png in the left corner while keeping them on the same line

```css
.topimages {
}
```

```html
<div class="topimages">
      <img height="125" length="125" src="images/logo.png" alt="image" style="position: abosolute; left: 0;">
      <img height="100" src="images/topbanner.png" alt="image" style="padding-left: 350px">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used your example and edited it. Run it to see the results.
Give parent `position:relative`, `text-align: center` and give `position: absolute`,`left: 0` to left image.

```css
.topimages {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="topimages">
  <img height="125" length="125" src="images/logo.png" alt="image" style="position: absolute; left: 0;">
  <img height="100" src="images/topbanner.png" alt="image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.topimages {
  text-align: center;
}

.topimages img:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="topimages">
  <img height="125" src="https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" alt="image1">

  <img src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" id="img2" alt="image2">

</div>
```